# IONIC Getting 500 "Internal Server error" form Post API Call

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-services, ionic-native, angular4-httpclient

I am getting 500 "Internal Server error" form ionic Post API Call, the api is working fine with postman.
I try with jquery ajax call as well inside ionic it is giving the success response, this is the post call I am making
since I am new to ionic so I am not getting where the problem exist weather its related to data or header and while making jquery I didn't use any header.

```
this.http.post("https://test/user/getdata", JSON.stringify({
 "username": "abcd",
 "country": "in",
 "token": "asjsjhaakjdhkjhhkjggjhggh"
 },{
   headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
   }
);
```

this call is giving me internal server error and If I change my header to **'application/json'** I am getting
**"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test/abc' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has 
been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."**
this error I have tried with putting these headers also
 **

1. (" access-control-allow-methods", 'GET, POST'),
2. ("access-control-allow-origin", "*"),
3. ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", 'true');

**
 but nothing worked. any help would be appreciable thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to enable CORS in the Backend API server by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors

Comment: Have you tried just using http instead of https?